# Issues in design/implementation of a software with kineticjs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I want to create an application that the user will have the ability to click on a picture add points and for each (certain) pairs of points the software will draw a line between those two. The points are draggable so the line must be able to readjust itself to the new position of its two ancors. The points are pre-specified and more than 5 or 6 (it can be 10 or more)

So my design so far.

- One kinetic stage
- One backgroundLayer which will have the following children:

  - backgournImage (will hodl the image to click on)
  - The points aded
  - the lines between the points

I guess for each of the lines  I will have to use a group that will contain the two ancors and the line. My problem is the following: Is there a convenient way to make sure a group is allready created for a certain pair of points so as not to create a new one when clicking on picture to add a new point?

```
stage.('contentClick', function(event){
    //create a new point
    // if  a group for the specific pair of ancors exists
    //add the point and draw the line
    // else this is the first point of the pair we are talking about
    // so create the group
    //and add the new point
    // add the group on the backgroundLayer
    //redraw stage
);
```

All points can have a specific id the name of the point.

I know the code for creating points groups adding them removing them checking parents etc, just don't know how could I do it with the least manual method. I mean it's not very productive checking each and every one of the points right?

Hope I am making some sense...

Comment: You don't have to group the 2 anchors and line. If you want to associate the 2 anchors+line you can give them all the same `name` property.  KineticJS name properties are like classes in CSS.

Comment: There is a catch, One ancor can be ancor to two different lines..So I can have three points A, B, and C and have two lines AB and BC or/and AC. What naming convention would serve me better?

Answer (score 0):

**One way is to track pairs of anchors that must be connected & reset their connecting lines when an anchor is dragged:**

- Create a Line to act as a connector.
- Create a js object that holds references to the 2 anchors and the line connecting them.
- Add the connection-object in an array.
- When any anchor is dragged, iterate the array & reset the connectors for the anchor that was dragged.

[image][image]

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/b7h5dfg5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var connectors=[];

    var a1=addAnchor(50,50,'one');
    var a2=addAnchor(150,50,'two');
    var a3=addAnchor(100,100,'three');
    addConnection(a1,a3);
    addConnection(a2,a3);


    function resetConnections(id){
        for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
            var c=connectors[i];
            if(c.id1==id || c.id2==id){
                c.line.points([
                    c.anchor1.x(),
                    c.anchor1.y(),
                    c.anchor2.x(),
                    c.anchor2.y()                
                ]);           
            }
        }
        layer.draw();
    }

    function addAnchor(x,y,id){
        var anchor=new Kinetic.Circle({
            id:id,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            radius: 10,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth:2,
            draggable: true
        });
        anchor.on('dragstart',function(){
            stage.find(".connector").each(function(n){ n.hide(); });
            layer.draw();
        })
        anchor.on('dragend',function(){ 
            stage.find(".connector").each(function(n){ n.show(); });
            resetConnections(this.id());
        })
        layer.add(anchor);
        layer.draw();
        return(anchor);
    }

    function addConnection(anchor1,anchor2){
        var line=new Kinetic.Line({
            name:'connector',
            points:[anchor1.x(),anchor1.y(),anchor2.x(),anchor2.y()],
            stroke:'black'
        });
        layer.add(line);
        line.moveToBottom();
        layer.draw();
        connectors.push({
            line:line,
            id1:anchor1.id(),
            id2:anchor2.id(),
            anchor1:anchor1,
            anchor2:anchor2
        });
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag red anchors and connectors will follow</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```